# Can I repair Damaged Mods?

Tags: warframe

I sometimes get mod drops that say they're damaged. Is there any way to repair them? Should I bother levelling them? Or is this just the game's way of indicating quality? (I so far am just ignoring damaged mods in favour of ones that aren't damaged, but if I can make these useful to me, I'd like to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't repair damaged mods.  Instead, you have to find the normal versions of these mods elsewhere in the solar system.

Damaged mods are generally weaker than their non-damaged counterparts, plus they also have less upgrades available.

If you're looking for a specific mod, its drop locations may be listed in the in-game Codex.  It's also a good idea to check the [Warframe Wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/WARFRAME_Wiki).

Comment: On a side note, of the damaged mods you receive by completing quests/junctions, the only one I still have yet to replace with a non-damaged mod is Equilibrium... because it only drops from a specific boss with a fairly low drop chance (~7.5%).  Which was also bad luck on my part because I fought said boss at least 8 times while farming for Nekros warframe parts.